# Edit/view the command functions referenced by the key binding JSON script in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, json, terminal, subprocess

Here's a custom key binding I have in ST3:

`{ "keys": ["super+shift+e"], "command": "open_dir", 
    "args": {"dir": "$file_path", "file": "$file_name"} }`

I would like to edit/view the command functions referenced in this JSON key binding (e.g. `open_dir`, which opens Finder). I want to see the code behind `open_dir` to see how it works.

The JSON file of this key binding is `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap`. I've done file searches in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/` as well as in `Applications/Sublime Text/` for command names such as `open_dir` but I still can't find the code of the commands that the JSON script is referencing.

Is there a way to find and view the commands that the JSON script is referencing?

**EDIT**: Thanks and apologies to those who commented before I made this edit. I've changed the title and the question text pretty heavily to try to be clearer since the post got put on hold.

Comment: Can you put some code here? (i.e `your-json-file.json` and `your-python.py`.

Comment: A JSON file is not executable by itself, so unless you're using something else to interpret the JSON file, and do something with the contents, no.

Comment: You could write a python function that parses the JSON object and then creates an subprocess based on the value of a key.

Comment: Trying to have JSON call Python is like trying to have your shopping list load your groceries into your car; JSON doesn't *do* things.

Comment: @FrankAK I edited my main post to include relevant information about what exactly I'm trying to do.

Comment: Sublime probably loads all builtin functions, then calls something like `eval("open_dir")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is parsed, not interpreted. Plus they are not executable, much like a plain text file.

Therefore, you use python as normal to run a subprocess, but from a parsed value rather than a hard coded command

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit unclear from your question what your end goal really is.  You should provide some examples.

If you are looking to parse JSON data, extracted from a file, and execute in the terminal, then using the subprocess is likely the way to go.

[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: I've explained the reasoning behind my question with the edit to my main post. Hopefully that helps clarify.